# Function how to show whether it is pointwise or uniform convergent?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

My sequence is : $s_n=\frac{2}{3+n|x|}$ for real x and n $\in \mathbb{N}$

Now I have done this:

$\lim_\limits{n \to 0}  \frac{2}{3+n|x|}= \frac{2}{3}$

$\lim_\limits{ n \to \infty} \frac{2}{3+n|x|}= 0$

Now it is pointwise convergent to these 2.

Now I want to show if it uniform convergent or not:

$\left|\frac{2}{3+n|x|}-0 \right| \leqslant \left|\frac{2}{nx}\right| \leqslant \left|\frac{2x}{nx}\right|\leqslant \left|\frac{2}{n}\right| $

Now it is with this way because I have found a function for which this applies.

Is this correct? Can I simply multiply the upper part by $2$ to make it independent from $x$ ?

Edit:
Now I have this

For x= 1/n

$\lim_\limits{ n \to \infty} sup \left|\frac{2}{3+n|1/n|}-0 \right| = 2/3 \neq 0 \ $

So it is not uniform convergent.

Now my second function

The sequence is : $s_n=\frac{2|x|}{3+n|x|}$ for real x and n $\in \mathbb{N}$

I have done this:

$\lim_\limits{n \to 0} \frac{2x}{3+n|x|}= \frac{2|x|}{3}$ Is this now still pointwise convergent due to the function?

$\lim_\limits{ n \to \infty} \frac{2|x|}{3+n|x|}= 0 ?$

$\lim_\limits{ n \to \infty} sup \left|\frac{2|x|}{3+n|x|}-0 \right| \leqslant \left|\frac{2|x|}{nx}\right| \leqslant \left|\frac{2}{n}\right| $

So this is now 100% uniform convergent, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most easy is to use sufficient and necessary condition of uniform convergence
$$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$$
In your example function $s_n(x)=\frac{2}{3+n|x|}$ is even on $\mathbb{R}$, and you can find, that sup reached in $x=0$. Hence?

Comment: I have done this. Is it correct? The sup is used for our f(x) only right? To take the highest? Thanks. So I guess I have to subtract the 2/3

Comment: $\sup$ should be taken for difference. Its a lot of things needs to be noted: 1) why you take limits with $n \to 0$? 2) what means $n=\frac{1}{n}$? Simply followed to my answer gives not uniform convergence for first functional sequence. For second you need find $\sup$. Feel free to set any question, but be careful with editing initial task.

Comment: I have calculated n-> 0 to find all limits. Forgot to use the sup limit. And x=1/n my bad

Comment: So is it $\frac{6-6x-2n|x|}{9+3n|x|}=\frac{6-6x-2}{9+3}=\frac{4-6x}{12}=\frac{4-6x}{12}$ For n = 1/x now it is not 0 and so not uniform ?

Comment: How you obtain this? Limit function in second example $s_n=\frac{2|x|}{3+n|x|}$ is again $0$. And, sorry, but one more time: why you take $n \to 0$? You have $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it have not limit point $0$.

Comment: Wait don't I have to subtract by the sup limit? I have subtracted by 2/3

Comment: Firstly you find limit function, then you consider difference between it and functional sequence and find $\sup$ from modulus. And at last you calculate limit with respect to $n \to \infty$. Exactly follow formula.

Comment: But I did this ? Why sup from modulus?  I have used the limit of 0 in my original post for the subtraction. And I have subtracted both times by 0 so it is correct or not?

Comment: Because it is formula, theorem, proved necessary and sufficient condition. We can discuss it separately, if you want, but lets do it in separate question. Here simply use it. Subtraction from $0$ is correct in both cases and uniform convergence in second example is also correct.

Comment: So is it correct now? ^^ Thanks a lot! Thought I will never understand this. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Yes, but, for formality, its more good to write $\sup \left|\frac{2|x|}{3+n|x|}-0 \right| \leqslant \frac{2}{n}$. And then consider limit.